# Site login is Oauth consumer, should web api be an Oauth provider?

Tags: oauth, asp.net-web-api

I'm confused about this...

If a website is an oauth consumer (facebook), and then builds a web API with some restricted access... and implements oauth on that end, how would that work?

Wouldn't it just be adding an extra layer of trying to login to facebook? How do others normally approach something like this?